# When i try to post date i get the field data must be a date error

Tags: c#, httpclient

Im trying to send date to a server and when i try to send date with time i get this error.
Server accepts date with this format : `Date: 24.11.2023 г. 13:45:00`

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, string>
{

    { "Date", _citizen.Date },

};
```

i try to send date like this as a string..

If i send it like 2.2.2024 г. 13:30:00 there is no problem but when i try to send 13.2.2024 г. 13:30:00 i got error.(when days greater then 12)

i think i got problem with client-side validation because it thinks 13 is month.

I hope i can explain my problem.By the way its Bulgarian format.

Im hoping to fix this annoying issue, actually i got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the date before putting it in the payload. Create a new string with the correct formatted date and use that in the payload instead.

If your system format (region settings) is different to the server's expected input format, the date will be scrambled on sending the data. Especially true if the server is accepting a `string` for the date input.

Comment: system format (Bulgarian) same with server's expected. What should i do?

Comment: Since it will be a `string` when sending to the server, just create a new string with the correct formatted date and use that in the payload.

Comment: Oh thanks but how can i add "г." beetwen date and time

Comment: By expanding it out as a new string, for example: `var payloadDate = _citizen.Date.Day + "." + _citizen.Date.Month ... ;` There is most likely a format method you can use where you define the format using a string like `dd-MM-yyyy` and output the date using it.